# How to count consecutive shifts greater than 5 in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a group of employees and need to find a way to count the number of times an employee works greater than 5 days a row. Shifts are indicated by a different letter (H, P, Y, X) given the start time. I have attached a Google Sheet with the examples. Different combos of shifts do not matter, as long as over 5 days in a row are worked. I've tried some IF statements and some Arrays, but not very good at this coding thing. The actual Google Sheet will be much more expansive than this sample one, with the pay periods from last year, and will continue for the foreseeable future. Please help.

Below is a Google Sheets link for the example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Maov8GcWN7BgG4rR1eH8tuNIZqSr7isr38aPlFOVJQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be done with string manipulation like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    rows( 
      query( 
        len( 
          transpose( 
            split( 
              regexreplace( 
                join( 
                  "", 
                  filter( 
                    regexreplace(trim(B3:B) & " ", "(?i)^([HPYX] )$", "_"), 
                    isnumber($A3:$A) 
                  ) 
                ), 
                "[^_]", 
                " " 
              ), 
              " ", false, true 
            ) 
          ) 
        ), 
        "where Col1 > 5", 0 
      ) 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Maov8GcWN7BgG4rR1eH8tuNIZqSr7isr38aPlFOVJQ/edit#gid=1181383249) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I was trying to copy over the formula to the original spreadsheet and one thing that is causing some pain is that in the original, the H, P, Y, X shifts are also denoted by at least one following lowercase letter (i, s, r, tw). And the formula is not liking that @doubleunary

Comment: Consider sharing another publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data. Also show your _hand-entered_ expected results there.